# Why is universe expanding?

Tags: cosmology, universe, space-expansion

Okay, this question may sound silly:
base on the observation
Besides an expanding universe, would there be other possibilities?

Would it be possible, say, there exists a fundamental repelling interaction among all partices, which is proportional to distance (e.g. $Ae^{ar}$, where $A$ extremely small?)

p.s. I know it is a kind of silly question, but if you downvote it, at least please tell me why.

Comment: Bound systems are not expanding, more importantly, though, your potential is extremely sensitive to distance and it doesn't lead to a Hubble type expansion, at all. Put it into Newton and calculate the solution!

Comment: that's a good way to start thinking, thanks for answering.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. The universe *was* expanding because it had "momentum" left over from inflation. It currently *is* expanding because of that and because dark energy has a negative pressure and is the dominant form of energy now.

Comment: I am sorry, I have edited my question, does it make sense now? (sorry, I am still studying undergrad physics, not quite familiar with cosmology)

Comment: If there were a fundamental repelling interaction, then nothing would move because the universe is populated fairly homogeneously with matter. The galaxies would feel said repelling force equally from all directions and, thus, wouldn't move. What you seem to be thinking about is if there was a repelling force generated by our galaxy alone, but that would be too unlikely to accept as a theory

Comment: There are, of course, many other reasons why it isn't a repelling force, but since that was just an example of an alternative, there's no point in dwelling on it

Comment: Thanks for answering, it is true, I have thought of that too, but I was wondering there exist a potential such that the infinite sum converges, that of course we can know probably only by calculation.

Comment: I have answered my very question, feel free to tell me if it does not make sense to you.

Comment: have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_energy#Effect_of_dark_energy:_a_small_constant_negative_pressure_of_vacuum

Answer (score 1):

Some galaxies are known to be expanding away from us faster than the speed of light.  This is only possible if it is the underlying universe getting bigger.  It isn't possible that these galaxies are simply moving faster than the speed of light as your argument suggests as this violates the principles of special relativity.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I am not familiar with special relativity, but I have read essay written by Sean Carroll that special relativity makes sense only in short range, in a very large scale, special relativity is not well defined, hence it is nothing special to be "faster" than light when it comes to universe expending.

Comment: @ShingLau, expansion faster than speed of light is allowed but this is because it is the space that is expanding, rather than the galaxies moving.  The galaxies themselves are not able to move faster than the speed of light (due to relativity) however if more space is added between us and the galaxy (as is the case in an expanding universe), it may give the appearance that the galaxy is moving faster than light speed (although it is not).  But this is how we know expansion is due to increased addition of space, rather than due to simple movement of galaxies.

Comment: Thanks, I have just tried to answer my very question, feel free to read it to see if it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I am attempting answering my question based on one fact and one assumption (actually there are one more fact/ observation - Redshift):

The fact is:
inertial frame. which, to a good approximation, earth itself (ignore its rotation, irrelevant to our discussion) is an inertial frame.

The assumption is:
Earth is no special place.

Hence the logical consequence(only possibility) is that the universe expanding instead of there exist converging interactions proportional to distance.

Comment: this answer looks good too. I think there are many reasons why we know the universe is expanding and this is certainly one of them, good job.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to give a mainly-link answer, but [*Alan Guth's video about dark energy*](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDIQtwIwA2oVChMI0peWwtPyxwIVSXE-Ch3SUQgi&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D53KBxamv09U&usg=AFQjCNFUI6J8cnlHQro30Umx-7GDVG3b3g&sig2=IsXxHWfjGNG6d7reT1WCng&bvm=bv.102537793,d.cWw) was very educational to me.
He's the cosmologist who's a primary author on the *inflationary universe* theory.

Basically, if I can summarize it, there can be a kind of material that has repulsive gravity rather than attractive gravity. In addition, its density in space does not necessarily decrease as it expands, and this is the cause of the initial big bang, after which it *mostly* decayed into ordinary energy-matter with attractive gravity, but there's still some around, causing the cosmic expansion to accelerate.